# Space in fraction

Tags: spacing, fractions

See distance from/to fractionline...How can i lower little bit    `\partial W`?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\frac{\partial W}{\partial t}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The space is there by design, to allow room for letters with descenders. This way, the baselines of the numerators of two consecutive fractions will align whether a descender is present or not.

Comment: \raisebox{-.4ex}{\partial W} solves problem...So i need small macros for 'Catitals' in numerators...

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili Since you have found a solution to your question, please consider posting it as an answer and then accepting it. It'll make it easier for others who encounter the same problem to find the solution.  I also would make sure to look at the behaviour with letters such as *q*,*p* and *j*.